# How to upload data to parse or google cloud back end

Tags: parse-platform, backend, android

I am creating an android application that is connected to the parse back end at the moment. My question is how do i upload data like text, images,and video from my computer directly to parse and then be able to call it from my app. ive been doing some research and i seen things like rest api and accessing it through Http. i just want to see whats best for my case.

so basically my question is how do i upload data to parse from my computer.
im kind of new to this and any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you just need to upload a few files then you can do it from the Parse dashboard. For a large number of files write a script that call the Parse REST API

Comment: Thanks a lot. do you know any good tutorials on parse REST api

Comment: I think their official docs are good enough for learning to use their REST API. https://parse.com/docs/rest